# Cordova Alert Button

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, button, alert

I'm trying to put an alert on a button in Cordova, I don't understand why it's not working.
I started a new cordova blank project with console.
See below my code :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"> 
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id = "textlocal">Test Local</button>`

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        document.getElementById("textlocal").addEventListener("click", textLocal);

    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },

    function textLocal(){
            alert('test');
        }
};
app.initialize();
```

**Maybe my textLocal() function is not at the right place, but I can't figurate how to fix it.**
Thank you a lot for your patience and your help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a JavaScript error in your code. Please try this code now. Maybe you need to add the "textLocal" listener up to the "deviceready" listener.

**Code**

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        document.getElementById("textlocal").addEventListener("click", this.textLocal);

    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    textLocal: function() {
        alert('Test');
    }
};
app.initialize();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your comment is interesting, I also think the function may be wrote like this, however I tried your solution but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a syntax error.

And this function never will call if you not associate with button.

You need put a onclick listener. You can use onclick tag like this:

`<button id="textlocal" onclick="textLocal()">Test Local</button>` (without space)

or using jquery

`$("#textlocal").on("click", textLocal);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from head tag and try

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

If still its not working, your deviceready function executing before DOM load. So you should put it inside $(document).ready if you are using jquery or just in onload event. By the way add addEventListener is not good approach for such simple operation, just use onclick listener.

Comment: Its impossible. May be you want to code in your own way. But if this code doesn't run means you want to achieve something beyond the concept of javascript and dom.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think so, I just want to know how to call a function in a new cordova project, and I first start with a simple alert function. I think I didn't do the right thing...

Comment: Everyone's answer on this question is right. They all gave right answer needed for your alert. But instead of accepting anyone's answer or atleast comment thank you. You said our code is not working. And posted the same answer that I had described and vsantos had the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I allow myself to bring an interesting way to understand why it's not working. I'm not so familiar with cordova development but I create a cordova project on Visual Studio and get this :

index.html

```
<button id="textlocal" data-role="button">Alert</button>
```

index.js (in ondevice ready) :

```
$('#textlocal').click(textLocal);
```

test.js :

```
function textLocal() {
alert('test');}
```

**And this solution works.** However, **I wouldn't like to work on visual studio** but directly with command prompt and outside any editor.
It's a little the same thing as my demand above, but still can't find a way to make it happend. Hope that could help you to answer my problem.
Thank you.